# Progress View does not want to hide

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

Again with a strange behavior, this time from a progressView.
Defined a progressView in my .h file and .m file :

.h file :

```
IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
```

.m file :

```
self.progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];

self.progressView.center = CGPointMake(390, 70);
[self.view addSubview:self.progressView];
self.progressView.hidden = YES;
```

When I need it to show, just set the .hidden property to NO and it shows up, do its business very well.
But the problem is that when the job is done I want it to leave the stage but it won't ...

I tried :

```
[self.progressView removeFromSuperview];
self.progressView.hidden = YES;
self.progressView.alpha = 0.0f;
```

Not at the same time of course, but nothing is working. It's just as it was disconnected from the view and I don't understand why.

Does somebody have any brilliant (as usual) idea ???

Thanks and hope to discuss with somebody tomorrow, now it's time to go to bed ....

Enjoy

Comment: WHY ARE YOU YELLING AT US?

Comment: Q: why are u using an IBOutlet but create the view in code?

Comment: Hello vikingosegundo, I don't understand "Yelling" as I don't use capital letters ... ?

Comment: Anyway, what should I use then, @property ? I always used one or the other without any problem, could you develop what could be the problem ? I tried to define it with property and nothing changed, still not able to hide it while able to show it in the beginning ... Thanks for your answer

Comment: you did use capital letters. Unheilig changed that. You should check the documentation what IBOutlet is and what @property.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
@property(weak) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
```

and

```
UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
[self.view addSubview:progressView];
self.progressView = progressView;
self.progressView.center = CGPointMake(390, 70);
```

and later

```
[self.progressView removeFromSuperview];
```

probably your code is releasing your progress view too fast and your property/outlet is not referencing it anymore.

With my code the view will own the progress view, before it is assigned to a not owning property.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I try that as soon as possible and come back with result ... Hold the line ...

Comment: OK, it doesn't work like that neither but I found out this :
I'm using a connection manager to fire the progressView and the 3 methods => connection didReceiveResponse: connection didReceiveData: and connectionDidFinishLoading:
I can act on anything until connectionDidFinishLoading but from the start of that method I have no more access to ANY label or textfield or the progressView properties. I see no special code forbidding access so it should be something related to the connection manager itself. I found no doc about it so far ...